# How to get the shortest file size on aliases?

Tags: macos, alias

I realize [a bit of why they are so big](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81671/why-are-the-alias-so-big-in-filesize-in-mountain-lion). Actually, they used to be [small enough](http://www.upenn.edu/computing/printout/archive/v08/5/aliases.html) (around **2kb**) and [still magical about keeping the file link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(Mac_OS)).

I can also see [a few ways to "shorten" it](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3988292?tstart=0), including one I've been using for a long time already, which is a simple [service to create symlinks](https://superuser.com/a/24520/28411) instead. There's an issue there:

### Symlinks are not aliases

- They break way too easily. An alias can keep linked to the origin most of the times.
- Some software will treat symlinks differently from Aliases. Here, each one have their use, and eventually I'll use one or another.
- Not as easy to create as aliases -> use <kbd>CMD + ALT</kbd> while dragging n' dropping files!

So, **forget symlinks** for this question, please!

As for the actual way to shorten it ([described on the already linked apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3988292?tstart=0)) they are way unpractical. First you need to install Shrink Alias with Shortcuts (because the first is unsupported in newer OS X's and the second is a hack to make it available as a Service) and [Delete Data Fork workflow](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Automator-Actions---Workflows/Delete-Data-Fork.shtml). Then manually apply both to each alias. Eventhough you can do it by selecting all files in Finder, again, you still have to do it for each time you create aliases and it's many hacks to keep updated on the next OS'es.

Isn't there a simple *Service Workflow*, *Automator* or *AppleScript* which could do  all that automatically whenever I create a new alias, maybe by hooking up on the [Alias Manager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Alias_Manager/index.html)?

I doubt there is a [secret](http://secrets.blacktree.com/) to help with any of this...

How about some other new idea about all this?

Comment: What is a small alias if not a symlink?

Comment: @Mark symlink is the smallest kind of file link, but it's very different from Alias as you can see from the first 2 bullet points.

Comment: What is a small alias then?

Comment: It's an alias pre-Lion without thumbnails and preferably with less than 2kb. I'm not sure if those keep the magical link, but I bet it wouldn't need to be much bigger than that.

Comment: @Mark Thanks to your comments, I've heavily edited the question, in hope it's clearer now. Feel free to delete your comments, so I could clean up and delete mine as well! ;P

Comment: It's as bad as it can be: Those **huge alias files do not even use HFS+ filesystem compression**, so they **really consume storage exorbitantly**! I was bothered by this, but thought "Maybe it's not as bad as Finder's 'Get Info' reports and HFS+ compression is activated on those huge aliases in the backend, those icon bitmap resources considerably compressed? Created `~/Desktop/Folder` and aliased it to `~/Desktop/Folder-Alias`, then ran `afsctool -v` on them. **Total size:** `Data fork 1.825.604 + resource fork 3.649.830 + xattr 32 overhead 536 + file overhead 5262 = 5.481.264 bytes`

Comment: Did not find any hint yet on how to tame that beast.

Comment: Like so much crap in life, I had to just learn to live with them... Found no healthier solution either! :(

Comment: In macOS 10.12 Sierra the file size of an alias to a file or folder without a custom icon, that is with the default icon of its corresponding file type, is finally again down to a few bytes, about 800-900 Bytes (depending on  inode, filename, filepath, and all the relevant alias info encoded into it) . Hurray!

Comment: Now all of us who have their 100-1000s of aliases with 1-5 MB each would love to see a batch process which turns them into the now possible small Aliases, and gain a few GB of disk space :-) Anyone with a solution, feel free to share!

Answer (score 1):

In High Sierra, the following works: just select the alias and run Finder command "Show Original" (command-R).  This trims the alias size down to a minimum.  This brought an alias that was previously 24 Mb down to 8 Kb.

Comment: i dropped out of mac over a year ago. sorry, i've got no idea why this was downvoted... sounds quite reasonable. ;)